# create a UDP to serial bridge with socat

Tags: serial-port, netcat, udp, socat

I have a piece of software that transmits data over a UDP connection. However in our system we can transmit data only over a serial port. I was thinking of making a bridge between a UDP and serial using `socat`. However I'm not familiar with it very well. Tried going over a few tutorials but they were not helpful. Also tried reading the manual, but it wasn't helpful as well.

I found an [example here](http://www.drdobbs.com/embedded-systems/serial-sockets/240149514), and adapted it to my needs. Here is what I have on my embedded system (it has a static IP)

```
$ socat -v udp4-datagram:172.24.176.207:54321 \
   open:/dev/ttyS0,raw,nonblock,waitlock=/tmp/s0.locak,echo=0,b115200,crnl
```

and here is what I have on my host machine (has a static IP as well)

```
$ socat -v udp4-datagram:172.24.176.116:54321 \
   open:/dev/ttyUSB0,raw,nonblock,waitlock=/tmp/s0.locak,echo=0,b115200,crnl
```

You would have to excuse me, but I'm illiterate in `socat` and `networking` in general.

Several comments and questions.

1. What does `open:/dev/ttyUSB0,raw,nonblock,waitlock=/tmp/s0.locak,echo=0,b115200,crnl` mean? Where would I find description of it? I understand `/dev/ttyUSB0` and `b115200`, but what is the rest?
2. On an embedded system (172.24.176.207) I ran a `netcat` server:

   ```
   $ nc -ul 172.24.176.207 54321
   ```

   and on the host machine I sent a UDP packet:

   ```
   $ echo -n "hello" | nc -4u -w1 172.24.176.207 54321
   ```

   but nothing happened. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

#### echo server setup

I used `socat` to set up a UDP echo server like this:

*echo server*

```
$ socat UDP4-LISTEN:54321,fork EXEC:cat
```

*echo client*

```
$ echo -n "hello" | nc -4u -w1 192.168.56.101 54321
hello
```

#### tcpdump tip

When debugging this, I like to monitor the network, so will run this to monitor the 'echo server'

```
$ tcpdump -i any -vnn port 54321
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
22:33:21.280053 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8684, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 33)
    192.168.56.1.62439 > 192.168.56.101.54321: UDP, length 5
22:33:21.282140 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40761, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 33)
    192.168.56.101.54321 > 192.168.56.1.62439: UDP, length 5
```

**NOTE:** This above tip can be heavily modified to debug anything that's going on between your socat/nc server and its clients.

#### Making sense of socat arguments

I too find the configuration of `socat` *exhausting* at times. But like anything else, it's easiest to grasp if you break it up into smaller bits.

```
$ socat -v udp4-datagram:172.24.176.116:54321 \
   open:/dev/ttyUSB0,raw,nonblock,waitlock=/tmp/s0.locak,echo=0,b115200,crnl
```

So the first 2 switches should be somewhat obvious:

- `-v` - verbose
- `udp4-datagram:172.24.176.207:54321` - UDP listening on port 54321
- `open:/dev/ttyUSB0` - sets up sending intput/output to your USB #0 device
- `raw` - raw mode, passes input/output unprocessed
- `nonblock` - opens/uses files in nonblocking mode
- `waitlock=/tmp/s0.locak`- creates a waitlock file - guards against multiple `socat`'s
- `echo=0` - disables local echo on server
- `b115200` - sets the baud rate to 115,200 bits
- `crnl` - converts newlines from `\n` to `\r\n`

Incidentally if you look in the `socat` man page, there are many examples. Also full descriptions of the above switches are there as well.

#### References

- [socat man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat)